# How should I prepare for an interview in the same department

Tags: interviewing

I've been working for a few years with the same team of 20-30 developpers and I want to apply for a new job within the same department. Means I'm going to be interviewed by a boss that already knows me, the technical interview will be done by coworkers (friends) I've been working with everyday. I know more than enough how I should act on a regular interview

- Dressed to make a good impression
- Firm handshake
- Sell yourself

This kind of feels weird since I know all of them and they know me personally. How should I approach this interview since I don't want to make too much but I don't want to act like I'm not taking this seriously.

Comment: @gnat I would consider this a bit different purely because that question is focused on the company at large vs within the same department.

Comment: @RualStorge http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Answer (score 1):

First, this *IS* still an interview. You should still dress the part, still act in a professional manner, and so forth exactly like you would any other interview.

Ultimately the only difference you should take compared to a normal interview is it's safe to say they'll just brush past the "does he fit with our team" portion. (Since if you didn't you'd have been long gone by now)

Otherwise you still need to act in a professional manner, and respond to any questions they have, comments, concerns, etc in exactly the same way you would as if you were interviewing at someplace new. (by all means you may respond to them in a friendly manner appropriate to your familiarity, but keep it professional)

The good news is, long as you're fit for the role you have a really good advantage on your side in pursuing this role. (It's not something that guarantees you the spot, but probably guarantees you consideration)

Answer (score -1):

1. They know you, so they won't be asking questions about your background and your work experience.
2. The only reason you might want to dress up for an interview is to create some kind of first impression. Forget about giving a first impression part, they already know you. Dress up if it makes you feel good and it builds your self-confidence.
3. They might you ask you why you want the job, so be prepared for that.
4. They'll most likely run you through some scenarios to gauge how ready you are for the position, so be prepared for that.
5. If the position presumes some kind of unique expertise on your part, they might ask you questions to gauge your level of expertise.
6. You have the inside track. You sell yourself by showing that you are qualified for the position and you know what you're supposed to know. Again, if they know that you know, they'll most likely won't waste any time on what you know. On the other hand, what you don't know and can't figure out will be of high interest to them. Forget about spinning your answers, they know you. If you b.s., they'll most probably won't forgive you for it.

That's pretty much it.